# mytheme_links__system_main_menu($variables) function not being called

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have created a custom template and i don not want the default menu structure of drupal 7.So I thought of creating a custom structure for this.In my custom theme page.tpl page i have called the 
the following theme function.

`<?php  print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu'))); ?>`

I have created a new custom template.php file in the same theme directory where the page.tpl.php resides and defined the following function

```
function mytheme_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $html = "<div>\n";
  $html .= "  <ul>\n"; 

  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $html .= "<li>".l($link['title'], $link['path'], $link)."</li>";
  }

  $html .= "  </ul>\n";
  $html .= "</div>\n";

  return $html;
}
```

but tthis function that is being included in the tempkate.php file does not seem to be called for some reason.Could someone please help me as o why the `mytheme_links__system_main_menu` is not called.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you cleared your caches/rebuilt your theme registry since adding this?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you are saying about creating `a new custom template.php file in the same theme directory as the page.tpl.php resides,` but most themes will only look for one `template.php` file and that is in the toplevel directory of the theme, so this function (named appropriately) should probably go in there....